# Exporting to CSV file in SSIS from query is mixing up rows and columns

Tags: ssis

I am trying to export data from a query to CSV in SSIS. But the resulting CSV file is mixing up rows and columns.
I am using `|`as a delimiting character.The problem comes when the column data is few i think. Could it be a datatype size issue?

**Update:**

Here is an example of the text i a trying to export.
   at MyGeneration.dOOdads.BusinessEntity.Save()   at HCMIS.Desktop.Forms.WorkFlow.Receipt.HandleReceiveDocShortage(DataRowView dr, ReceiveDoc rec, Int32 receiveDocID)   at HCMIS.Desktop.Forms.WorkFlow.Receipt.SaveReceive()   at HCMIS.Desktop.Forms.WorkFlow.Receipt.btnSaveReceipt_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

but such long texts are put on different columns.
I have removed new line, tab and '|', as i am using '|' as a column delimiter.
I have also tried using different string type for the file system.

Comment: Please post an sample of the output.  It's unclear from your description what the problem is.  I suspect the presence of row delimiters in your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data length shouldn't be an issue.  You'd get a truncation error in your Flat File Destination if the data were longer than your defined field size.

Usually when I've had things like this happen, it's because the source schema changed and I wasn't told about it.  SSIS doesn't do well when it thinks there are 10 columns and there are really 11.  Check to be sure you have the right number and order of columns in your Flat File Destination and Flat File connection.  Make sure the column mappings are right.

Then take a look at your Flat File Connection in SSIS.  Check the Columns page and verify the Row delimiter and the Column delimiter.  Also, on the General page, check the Header row delimiter and the Text qualifier.  Then make sure there are no identifiers embedded in your data.